# I'm trying to write this code in python only using while loops, but I don't know what is wrong with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A Python program that will output all of the pythogorean triples in a specified interval. (a,b,c) consists of three integers a < b < c such that the sum of the squares of the two smaller integers is equal to the square of the largest. the program should input an integer value n > 10 from the user and, using a series of nested while loops, determine and print out all the pythagorean triples with hypotenuse values ( length c ) in the closed interval [1, n] (one triple per line).

```
n=int(input("Enter on upper bound> 10:"))
c=1
a=1
b=1
if (a**2) + (b**2) == (c**2):
print ( a, b, c)
while (a**2) + (b**2) != (c**2) and c<n :
    c=c+1
     while (a**2) + (b**2) != (c**2) and b<c:
        b=b+1
       while (a**2) + (b**2) != (c**2) and a<b:
         a=a+1
```

Comment: you may want to rephrase the question...its a little confusing currently

Answer (score 1):

```
interval = [20, 50]

a = interval[0]
while a <= interval[1]:
    b = interval[0]
    while b <= interval[1]:
        c = interval[0]
        while c <= interval[1]:
            if (a**2 + b**2) == c**2:
                print(a, b, c)
            c += 1
        b += 1
    a += 1
```

Comment: I can only use while loops! @jfsturtz

Comment: why just while loop?

Comment: @astrosyam I'm trying to learn how to work with nested while loops.

Comment: @jfsturtz thank you for your answer. I had a question about how is a<b<c iincluded in the code?

Comment: Sorry; I missed that part originally.  Something like the edited example above closer?  It takes into account the defined interval.  It doesn't _specifically_ say a<b<c, but with the way the loops are defined, it is so each time through the loop(s).